# Laravel Eloquent Eager Load Sums

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sum, eager-loading

I am using eager load to load data before loading a page to make the load time faster.

```
$websites = Website::with('valid_click_ads',
                          'facebook_ads',
                          'google_ads')->get();
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get column summations this way. Ex:

```
$websites = Website::with('valid_click_ads:sum(clicks),sum(revenue)',
                          'facebook_ads:sum(clicks),sum(impressions)',
                          'google_ads:sum(clicks),sum(impressions)')->get();
```

This would make that load time even better! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing like this but you can use withCount method as a wrapper for sum this way :

```
$websites = Website::withCount(['valid_click_ads'=>function($query){
                         $query->select( DB::raw( "COALESCE(SUM(clicks),0)" ) );
                       },
                      'facebook_ads'=>function($query){
                         $query->select( DB::raw( "COALESCE(SUM(clicks),0)" ) );
                       },
                      'google_ads'=>function($query){
                         $query->select( DB::raw( "COALESCE(SUM(clicks),0)" ) );
                       }])->get();
```

COALESCE is a SQL function to return sum if exists else returns 0 instead of returning null.

**UPDATE :**
If you want to retrieve separate summation columns you have to define an index for each of them and alias them like this :

```
$websites = Website::withCount(['valid_click_ads as firstRes'=>function($query){
                     $query->select( DB::raw( "COALESCE(SUM(col1),0)" ) );
                   },
                   'valid_click_ads as secondRes'=>function($query){
                     $query->select( DB::raw( "COALESCE(SUM(col2),0)" ) );
                   }
                  ])->get();
```

etc..

Comment: This is great except that I need the sum of more than one value in each of those tables

Comment: Do you want to group them in a single value or multiple values i.e if you have a table with 3 column do you want to group the summation of 3 column into one value or 3 values such as the first value is the summation of column a , the second value is the summation of column b etc

Comment: I need the separate values

Comment: this way you need to define an index for each value and alias them i will update my ans